I am getting undefined variable error in my Laravel project
I am getting an error of undefined variable $message in my Laravel project. (this is just test code I wrote) I don't think my logic is correct, it must not be.
This is TestComponent.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class TestComponent extends Component
{
    public $message = "Hello, World!";

    public function mount($message){
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test-component'); 
    }
}


and here is my blade file test-component.blade.php
<div>
    @if(isset($message))
        {{ $message }}
    @else
        <p>$message is not set!</p>
    @endif

    @dump($message)
</div>


and then i just have the component included in my app.blade.php
<livewire:test-component />
I really don't get why this error is popping up, I was initially trying to pass data from a Filament Resource, and I was getting the same error so I just simplified it. I guess my logic must be wrong.
if i didn't use the text editor correctly, please bare with me, I am new to this... this is like my second question.
edit for further clarification: the undefined variable $message error persists when @dump($message) is outside the if check in the test-component blade file. when inside the if check, it just returns "$message is not set!"
the code below gives an error message undefined variable $message
<div>
    @if(isset($message))
        {{ $message }}
    @else
        <p>$message is not set!</p>
    @endif

    @dump($message)
</div>


the code below returns "$message is not set!"
<div>
    @if(isset($message))
        {{ $message }}
        @dump($message)
    @else
        <p>$message is not set!</p>
    @endif
</div>


the desired outcome is for $message to display "Hello, World!" as defined in TestComponent

Which line generates the error? The @dump call?

@ceejayoz hi, yes that's right

Then you should wrap it in a isset call like the other usage of $message.

@ceejayoz then i get $message is not set :") so $message is somehow not getting passed to the blade file.

The method mount() of the class TestComponent expects the parameter $message, if you do not provide it you get the error:
<livewire:test-component message="some message"/> 

If you want you can assign a default value in the mount() method so when the parameter is missing it gets that default value or you can use it for some logic:
class TestComponent extends Component
{
    public $message = "Hello, World!";


    public function mount($message = NULL) {

        if (!is_null($message)) {
            $this->message = $message;
        }
    }
}


i am getting the same error :c thanks though!

to clarify i am still getting "$message is not set!" instead of the actual message

"$message is not set!" is a strange error message , where do you find it (browser console, browser page...)? Do you pass the message parameter when you use the component? You should edit the question and specify how you use the component (e.g. in a parent blade file or in web.php)

Hi, I have edited my post and included a more detailed explanation

Ok, the "strange" message is the one you set in the @if now I understand better. However, if the variable $message is not found in the view (it cannot be NULL otherwise @dump() would return the value NULL) it means that there is some problem with the corresponding $message property of the class: check that the name is reported correctly and that the property is public
